# required validation does not work with input type file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, required

I am trying to apply the validation on file input type with the use of angular form and form properties like **$valid, $invalid, $pristine, $dirty, $touched**.

**Note**: All other validation except file type is working.

Code for html is like below:

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    ....
    ....
    ....
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
      <label>File</label>
      <input type="file" name="filetest" class="form-control" ng-model="user.file">
      <p ng-show="userForm.filetest.$invalid && !userForm.filetest.$touched" class="help-block">File is required.</p>
    </div>
    ....
    ....
    ....
</form>
```

but above snippet is not working. Please help me get out of this issue.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PELIGsgOVHebbrbKay9u?p=preview) is plnkr link for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file input does not have *required* attribute.

EDIT:
You also need to change condition in your *ng-class*: it should be

```
'has-error' : userForm.filetest.$invalid && !userForm.filetest.$pristine
```

instead of

```
'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine
```

The whole *div* element should look like this:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.filetest.$invalid && !userForm.filetest.$pristine }">
    <label>File</label>
    <input type="file" name="filetest" class="form-control" ng-model="user.file" required>
    <p ng-show="userForm.filetest.$invalid && !userForm.filetest.$touched" class="help-block">File is required.</p>
</div>
```

I think it works as expected after changind the div as mentioned.

Comment: hmm that was a typo.

Comment: I've edited my answer (I've found another typo) - it should be OK after intruducing suggested changes.